# How to remove additional fields in woocommerce order receipt?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WP-Checkout plugin to include extra fields in my checkout page, Those fields are included in the order receipt but I don't want that in order receipt. How to remove that?

Comment: Could you provide in your question links to your web site please, and also the real name of the plugin you are using (with a link) please.

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't exactly know how to remove these fields from order receipt page but i can suggest you a plugin that offers you to control field visibility on order page or in email.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/